# Windows XP cannot make VPN connection

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-xp

i want to make a VPN conenction from my windows xp machine but after i go to network connections and try to add new - the radio buttons are greyed out like in the picture [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/526/65181728.png/)

is there anything i can do ?

i am administrator on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your services:
Remote access connection manager and telephony services need to be running.  If they are, then something needs to be reinstalled or is corrupt.

System file checker:
Did you try the System file checker?  In a command prompt run 'sfc /scannow'.  That should at least find if not fix errors in your system files.  It may ask for a source windows cd.